# what does the curly braces {} do in ssreflect rewrite

Tags: coq, ssreflect

I am reading and playing with a ssreflect tutorial, and encountered a use of {} to quote things, which I don't quite understand:

```
Variables P Q : bool -> Prop.
Hypothesis P2Q : forall a b, P (a || b) -> Q a.
Goal forall a, P (a || a) -> True.
  move=> a HPa. move: {HPa} (@P2Q _ _ HPa) => HQa.
```

Can anyone explain what does `{HPa}` do to `HPa`?

BTW, the context was to introduce "views"??. I tried removing the `{}`, it still works but generates something different. And I don't know where to look for documentation for things like brackets or `@` for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

After some experiments and comparison, it seems that the function of `{H}` is to `clear H.` in Coq terms.

```
move: {HPa} (@P2Q _ _ HPa) => HQa.
```

gives

```
1 subgoals
a : bool
HQa : Q a
______________________________________(1/1)
True
```

while

```
move: (@P2Q _ _ HPa) => HQa.
```

gives the same thing except that `HPa` is kept intact in the context:

```
1 subgoals
a : bool
HPa : P (a || a)
HQa : Q a
______________________________________(1/1)
True
```